# Expected argument of type "integer", "App\Entity\Entreprise" given

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, symfony-forms

I uses two entitys: stagiaire and entreprise. Each stagiaire have one entreprise. I just need to save the id entreprise in the stagiaire table.
When I create a new stagiaire, choose an enterprise for him and save the form, I have the following error

> "Expected argument of type "integer" in the stagiaire controller:
> "App\Entity\Entreprise" given

Here is the code of the stagiaire entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\StagiaireRepository")
 */

class Stagiaire
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="civilite", type="string", length=3, nullable=false)
     */
    private $civilite = 'Mr';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=24, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=16, nullable=false)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Entreprise")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $entreprise;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=12, nullable=false)
     */
    private $status;

    public function __construct()
  {
    //$this->date       = new \Datetime();
    //$this->entreprise = new ArrayCollection();
  }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCivilite(): ?string
    {
        return $this->civilite;
    }

    public function setCivilite(string $civilite): self
    {
        $this->civilite = $civilite;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEntreprise(): ?int
    {
        return $this->entreprise;
    }

    public function setEntreprise(int $entreprise): self
    {
        $this->entreprise = $entreprise;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(string $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }
```

Here is the code of the form:

```
use App\Entity\Stagiaire;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class StagiaireType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $choicesCivil = [
            'Mr' => '1',
            'Mme' => '2'
        ];
        $choicesStatus = [
            'Gérant' => '1',
            'Salarié' => '2'
        ];

        $builder
            ->add('civilite', ChoiceType::class, [
                'data' => '1', // cochée par défaut
                'choices' => $choicesCivil,
                'expanded' => true,  // => boutons
                'label' => 'Civilité',
                'multiple' => false
            ])
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('prenom')
            ->add('entreprise', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'         => 'App:Entreprise',
                'placeholder'   => 'Choisir une entreprise',
                'choice_label'  => 'enseigne',
            ))
            ->add('status', ChoiceType::class, [
                'data' => '1', // cochée par défaut
                'choices' => $choicesStatus,
                'expanded' => true,  // => boutons
                'label' => 'Statut',
                'multiple' => false
            ])
            ->add('create', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Enregistrer', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Stagiaire::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use App\Entity\Stagiaire;
use App\Entity\Entreprise;
use App\Repository\StagiaireRepository;
use App\Form\StagiaireType;

class StagiaireController extends Controller
{
    public function fStagiaire($id,$cat,$action, Request $request)
    {
        if ($action=='insert') {
            $stagiaire = new Stagiaire();
        }
        elseif($action=='update' || $action=='delete') {
            $stagiaire = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getManager()
              ->getRepository('App:Stagiaire')
              ->find($id)
            ;
        }
        else { return;}

            $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(StagiaireType::Class, $stagiaire);
        
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) { 
          $form->handleRequest($request);

          if ($form->isValid()) {...
```

The error occurs at the line `$form->handleRequest($request);`
I am searching for a few days but I do not found the solution.
Has anybody an idea to help?

Answer (score 0):

Your `function setEntreprise(int $entreprise): self` is being given an object (an `App\Entity\Entreprise`), which is **not** what it is expecting. While the record in the database will be an int (the primary key `id` on the `Entreprise` entity - and in fact, it will be a separate database table that refers back to this record's ID with zero or more `Entreprise` records), it is made available to your code (from `getEntreprise()`) as the object (so returning the nullable int there would also fail when you come to read the linked entity out - it should be an empty `ArrayCollection()`).

Your setter & getter need to deal with the objects - and since it's a 'ManyToOne' relationship, there can more more than one.  You will likely also want an `addEntreprise()` function to be able to add more objects. The ORM will deal with saving the data in them to the database, and linking them back in later when this record is read in.

```
public function __construct()
{
    //$this->date       = new \Datetime();
    //$this->entreprise = new ArrayCollection();
}
# These lines say that `$this->entreprise` is an array - by default empty, but 
# it can be filled up with a number of linked objects.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your functions to accept an entreprise object instead of an id:

```
public function getEntreprise(): ?Entreprise
{
    return $this->entreprise;
}

public function setEntreprise(Entreprise $entreprise): self
{
    $this->entreprise = $entreprise;

    return $this;
}
```

and you have to add `use App\Entity\Entreprise;` to the Stagiaire class.

Comment: Wonderfull, you saved my life. Thanks a lot ! It works !

Comment: @Pierre-louisP please accept the answer to close your question.